Combinatorial optimization pathfinding algorithm
I have a optimization question phrased as a game. There is a $N$x$N$ square finite grid, $z(x,y)$ consisting of only 1's and 0's. Rules: You start anywhere on the left side of the grid $(x_1 = 1,y_1)$, and you have to make a horizontal jump anywhere you like $(x_2,y_2 = y_1)$, then you have to make a vertical jump $(x_3=x_2,y_3)$, then a horizontal jump ect. After each jump you subtract $1$ from the box you land on.
Aim: Find all jumps $(x_i,y_i)$ such that after $n$ jumps the grid is 'as close' to containing 0's as possible.
I realize this isn't very well mathematically defined so this is my attempt to formalize the problem:
\begin{equation}
\textrm{min} \sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N} (z(x_i,y_i) - J(x_i,y_i))^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textrm{subject to}\\ x_1 = 1 \\ x_i = x_{i-1}   \forall x_i \in 3,5,7... \\
y_i = y_{i-1}   \forall y_i \in 2,4,6...
\end{equation}
Where $J(x,y) = 1$ if $x=x_i$ and $y=y_i$, otherwise $J(x,y)=0$. If an analytical solution isn't possible, can you please outline an algorithm that will be best?

